# Unable to use go-ethereum evm utility

Tags: go-ethereum, evm

I am unable to use evm tool, e.g. leads to a crash:

```
$./evm --code 60ff60ff --debug run
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

Is this tool still supported ?

Comment: I'm using the 1.8.13 release on macOS if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in 1.8.15-stable:

```
$ evm --code 60ff60ff --debug run
0x
#### TRACE ####
PUSH1           pc=00000000 gas=10000000000 cost=3

PUSH1           pc=00000002 gas=9999999997 cost=3
Stack:
00000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ff

STOP            pc=00000004 gas=9999999994 cost=0
Stack:
00000000  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ff
00000001  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ff

#### LOGS ####

$ evm --version
evm version 1.8.15-stable
```